# How to use python regex to match words beginning with hash and question mark?

Tags: regex

This should be easy and this regex works fine to search for words beginning with specific characters, but I can't get it to match hashes and question marks.

This works and matches words beginning a:

```
r = re.compile(r"\b([a])(\w+)\b")
```

But these don't match:
Tried:

```
r = re.compile(r"\b([#?])(\w+)\b")
r = re.compile(r"\b([\#\?])(\w+)\b")
r = re.compile( r"([#\?][\w]+)?")
```

even tried just matching hashes

```
r = re.compile( r"([#][\w]+)?"
r = re.compile( r"([/#][\w]+)?"

text = "this is one #tag and this is ?another tag"
items = r.findall(text)
```

expecting to get:

```
[('#', 'tag'), ('?', 'another')]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\b` matches the empty space between a `\w` and `\W` (or between a `\W` and `\w`) but there is no `\b` before a `#` or `?`.

In other words: remove the first word boundary.

Not:

```
r = re.compile(r"\b([#?])(\w+)\b")
```

but

```
r = re.compile(r"([#?])(\w+)\b")
```

Comment: Bart K. That works - and also found I had additional bug in my code that added further to my confusion!  Many thanks.

Comment: The RE you gave will match `something like#this`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If those strings can occur, the OP can ask about it. Note that I can list a few more corner cases: what about strings that have a hash in it followed by `\w`'s, like this: `"this #is a ?string"`. It all depends on what is going to be parsed.

Comment: @Bart: `this #is a ?string` should get `is` and `string`, what's your point?

Comment: No I meant something different. My point is that we don't know exactly what the OP is trying to do based on the single example s/he posted. What if s/he's parsing something that is source code (or looks like such). Looking for a hash if that hash is inside a string literal or a comment will cause both our suggestions to fail. And what about when punctuation marks come into play like `this is one,#tag and`? Then your suggestion fails. In other words: it is for the OP to comment on my (or your) suggestion if something does not work properly. S/He knows the exact requirements after all.

Comment: @Bart: Notice that there is a leading `\b` in the question, so that's probably what the OP meant. I just pointed this out in case the OP didn't realize, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 2):

you are using Python, regex is the last thing to come to mind

```
>>> text = "this is one #tag and this is ?another tag"
>>> for word in text.split():
...   if word.startswith("#") or word.startswith("?"):
...     print word
...
#tag
?another
```

Comment: I understand that your code does answer the original question. But why do you think regular expressions are un-pythonic? I use them all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The first `\b` won't match before `#` or `?`, use `(?:^|\s)` instead.

Also, the `\b` at the end is unnecessary, because `\w+` is a greedy match.

```
r = re.compile(r"(?:^|\s)([#?])(\w+)")

text = "#head this is one #tag and this is ?another tag, but not this?one"
print r.findall(text)
# Output: [('#', 'head'), ('#', 'tag'), ('?', 'another')]
```

Comment: like learning to touch type - makeing the effort to become regex expert would be well worth the effort in the long run!  Thanks for contributing.