# Regex that returns hashtags with hash sign but excludes @ mentions

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have a regex that returns the words (excludes @mentions includes hashtags but removes the hash sign #)

```
import re
pattern=r'(?u)(?<![@])\b\w\w+\b'
pattern=re.compile(pattern)
pattern.findall('this is a tweet #hashtag @mention')
```

This returns

```
['this', 'is', 'tweet', 'hashtag']
```

What I need is a modification to this regex that returns **the hash sign with hashtag** so it should return:

```
['this', 'is', 'tweet', '#hashtag']
```

Note that my question is different from returning just @mentions and #hashtags I want both regular words and hashtags but I don't want @mentions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use python regex to match words beginning with hash and question mark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994615/how-to-use-python-regex-to-match-words-beginning-with-hash-and-question-mark)

Comment: How tied to using regex are you?  You should be able to do what you are trying to accomplish just using Python's native string methods.

Comment: I have to use regex because I'm giving it to sklearn's TFIDFVectorizer.

Comment: The mentioned duplicate question is different from this question. That only returns #hashtags not regular words. I want all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding '#?' to the pattern will let it match words that start with 0 or 1 hash symbols.

```
import re
pattern=r'(?u)(?<![@])#?\b\w\w+\b'
pattern=re.compile(pattern)
results = pattern.findall('this is a tweet #hashtag @mention')
print(results)
```

Resulting in:

```
['this', 'is', 'tweet', '#hashtag']
```